# How do i make a circular view collide with the paddle

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, uikit-dynamics

Whenever the circular view collides with the paddle on storyboard, it actually collides with the rectangular frame of the view. How do I resolve this issue. I have also tried `UIBezierPath`, `CAShapeLayer` and it doesn't seem to be working.

The red arrow is the colliding point, As it does not seem to be colliding with ball instead it collides with the frame of the view. once, the frame is touched with the paddle it bounces back and so on.

[image: screen snapshot]

Comment: How are you detecting the collision? Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: i haven't used Collision , written a func, which checks the  y axis of the paddle & the y axis of the view once they are Equal the ball bounces back i have used NS Timer to update the frame by 20px of the View  like 0 - 20- 40- 60 etc

Comment: You should have a look into UI Dynamics and/or SpriteKit.

Comment: @dasdom - i have tried UI Dynamics it's the same case the gap is still visible between the paddle & the Ball. i gotta create this app only on  storyboard itself not allowed to use Game scene or SpriteKit.

Comment: But with iOS 9 you can define arbitrary shapes for the dynamic elements. Setting the corner radius only changes the appearance.

Comment: @dasdom u mean UIBezierpath?, tried that too still not working. Any other way ?

Comment: I mean this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-229/?time=279

Comment: @dasdom thanks a ton for the link. i think it would help me out, but i get a serious issue using collision is that how do i apply gravity to the ever bouncing ball ? and when i use gravity & collision the paddle bar does not move i have applied pan gesture to it. which does not move horizontally. how do i fix these issues ?

Comment: @govindkumar Those seems like a completely different questions (one is how to apply gravity; the other is how to move paddle). If, after completely watching that video, you still have different questions, then post them separately, including a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each, i.e. the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem you describe. And next time, I'd suggest you be far more clear about what technology you're using (e.g. in this question, the fact that you were using UIKit Dynamics only came out in these comments, rather than being part of the question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using `UIDynamicAnimator`, you can define the `collisionBoundsType` and the `collisionBoundingPath` for the items that will be colliding, for example:

```
@IBDesignable public class BallView : UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    override public var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .Path
    }

    override public var collisionBoundingPath: UIBezierPath {
        let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0

        return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointZero, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
    }

    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        if shapeLayer == nil {
            shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }

        let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0

        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: bounds.size.height / 2.0), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true).CGPath
    }
}

@IBDesignable public class PaddleView : UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5 {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    override public var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .Path
    }

    override public var collisionBoundingPath: UIBezierPath {
        return UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: -bounds.size.height / 2.0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    }

    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        if shapeLayer == nil {
            shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }

        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).CGPath
    }
}
```

If you do this, and then add these items to your `UICollisionBehavior`, it will respect the collision boundaries you defined for the items. For example:

[image: collision animation]

---

The above illustrates a glancing blow, like in your original image. If you want it to bounce up even if it hits the edge of the paddle, you can specify the `collisionDelegate` for the `UICollisionBehavior` and give it a new direction:

```
let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [paddleView, ballView])
collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
collision.collisionDelegate = self
self.animator.addBehavior(collision)
```

And conform to `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate` and then implement `collisionBehavior(beganContactForItem:withItem:atPoint:)`:

```
func collisionBehavior(behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactForItem item1: UIDynamicItem, withItem item2: UIDynamicItem, atPoint p: CGPoint) {
    let postCollisionDirection = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [ballView])
    postCollisionDirection.addLinearVelocity(CGPoint(x: ballView.center.x - paddleView.center.x, y: -200), forItem: ballView)
    animator.addBehavior(postCollisionDirection)
}
```

That yields something like:

[image]

Clearly, you'll have to play around with this quite a bit to get the desired effect, but it illustrates the basic idea of detecting a collision and adding a linear velocity to the ball, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the Paddle i have applied UIPanGesture to move horizontally once, it touches the ball it bounces back , the paddle does not move at all seems not to be working with collision. why is that?

Comment: Look at your original image: if a real ball hit a paddle like yours, it would glance off to the side and downwards, not bounce back up.

Comment: That's Perfect, as you have displayed the ball colliding, with the edge of the Paddle, But it has to again bounce back to the top and hit the screen. is that possible with Collisions & Gravity ?

Comment: how do i move the Paddle horizontally , i have applied Pan Gesture to the PaddleView and gave x co-ordinates it only moves when the ball finishes bouncing after touching the screen. while bouncing it won't do am i following the wrong thing ?

Comment: i'm a newbie to stackoverflow & iOS development - LastComment  i've tried adding UISnapBehavior just like you said, in touchesBegan & touchesMoved it does not move accordingly, if you code update the answer with UISnapBehavior that would be great, Thanks a ton Rob.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler answer than the accepted answer would be to set the bounds to be elliptical instead of a defined path:

```
 override public var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .Elliptical
 }
```