# How do I create a circular collision bound with Swift UIDynamics?

Tags: swift, collision-detection, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, bounds

*This post has been modified to include a screenshot and code*...

It's been four days of trying to solve this, so can someone please clearly point out what's wrong with my implementation? It's my first time lol.

Have a look at my screenshot below.

-I'm using UIKit Dynamics and am trying to trap those 3 smaller balls inside the **ROUND** bounds of the larger ball, but they are only being kept inside the bounds of the larger ball's rectangle.

[image]

Here's the relative code:

The large bubble is created in IB and is declared in my class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var homeMainBubble: UIButton!

var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

var ballOne : UIImageView!
var ballTwo : UIImageView!
var ballThree : UIImageView!

var circlePath : UIBezierPath!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: homeMainBubble.frame.midX,y: homeMainBubble.frame.midY), radius: homeMainBubble.frame.width/2, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)}
```

In `viewDidAppear()`, I create a `UIBezierPath()`

```
//Adds or removes fake balls inside 'mainBubble()' when swiped up or down---------------------
func addOrRemoveFakeBalls(fakeBalls: String) {

    let ballOneIs = positionOneBubble()
    let ballImages = ["playBubble", "statsBubble", "settingsBubble", "cheatsBubble"]

    let ballOneImage = ballImages[ballOneIs.tag - 1] //Determines the image to used for 'fake ball 1' based on the bubble in position one
    var ballTwoImage : String = ""
    var ballThreeImage : String = ""

    if ballOneImage == "playBubble" { //Derivitive from ballOneImage, this determines the ball to the left & ensures correct array looping.
        ballTwoImage = ballImages[3]
    } else {ballTwoImage = ballImages[ballOneIs.tag - 2]}

    if ballOneImage == "cheatsBubble" { //Derivitive from ballOneImage, this determines the ball to the right & ensures correct array looping.
        ballThreeImage = ballImages[0]
    } else {ballThreeImage = ballImages[ballOneIs.tag]}

    switch fakeBalls {
    case "Add":
        ballOne = Ellipse(frame: CGRect(x: 125, y: 50, width: largeBubbleWidth, height: largeBubbleWidth))
        ballOne.image = UIImage(named: ballOneImage)
        ballOne.layer.zPosition = 1
        ballOne.alpha = 0.3
        ballTwo = Ellipse(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: mediumBubbleWidth, height: mediumBubbleWidth))
        ballTwo.image = UIImage(named: ballTwoImage)
        ballTwo.layer.zPosition = 1
        ballTwo.alpha = 0.3
        ballThree = Ellipse(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 50, width: mediumBubbleWidth, height: mediumBubbleWidth))
        ballThree.image = UIImage(named: ballThreeImage)
        ballThree.layer.zPosition = 1
        ballThree.alpha = 0.3

        homeMainBubble.addSubview(ballOne)
        homeMainBubble.addSubview(ballTwo)
        homeMainBubble.addSubview(ballThree)

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: homeMainBubble)

        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [ballOne, ballTwo, ballThree])
        gravity.magnitude = 1
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [ballOne, ballTwo, ballThree])

        collision.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "Circle" as NSCopying, for: circlePath)

        collision.collisionDelegate = self


       collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

        animator.addBehavior(collision)

    case "Remove":

        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        gravity.removeItem(ballOne)
        gravity.removeItem(ballTwo)
        gravity.removeItem(ballThree)
        collision.removeAllBoundaries()
        ballOne.removeFromSuperview()
        ballTwo.removeFromSuperview()
        ballThree.removeFromSuperview()

    default: break
    }

}
```

I've temporarily added `collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true` so that the balls don't drop off the screen, but with that commented out, why does the 'circlePath' UIBezierPath() not hold my smaller balls inside?

I have pretty much tried every approach and had every outcome EXCEPT for what I want :P.

What am I missing in order to keep the 3 smaller balls trapped inside the large ball's image (not rectangle) bounds?

THANK YOU for saving my week! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UIDynamics` then you can follow the advice in this other [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110371/how-do-i-make-a-circular-view-collide-with-the-paddle)

Namely, looks like you'll want to define `collisionBoundingPath` to be a `UIBezierPath` that is round.

```
override public var collisionBoundingPath: UIBezierPath {
    let radius = min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0

    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointZero, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
}
```

From there you can customize the behavior of the smaller balls hitting the outer edge through the `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate` (again, see linked question and answer).

*Update*

With more code posted, another issue I think you are having is the `UICollisionBehavior` isn't including the "main ball". You are only adding collision behavior between the 3 sub-balls, which is likely why they are not properly interacting with the big ball as you'd want. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's something I'll need to play around with more. When I've done that before, the smaller balls don't show up at all (I'm assuming it's because the smaller balls are added inside the larger ball, and if they are part of the same collision behaviour, their interaction starts off 'undefined'? But I'll see if I can focus on that part of it and play around. Thanks again for offering advice :)

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get it to work... including my animator reference view in the collision items produces very strange results.

Comment: I've tried subclassing UIView and customizing the CollisionBoundsType and CollisionBoundingPath, then adding a new instance of that subclass to add my smaller balls to, but nothing is encasing the balls within the circular view. The only way I can ever get the smaller balls to stay put inside their reference view is to call "collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true", which is a rectangle... Sadly, after 4 days I may simply have to abandon the idea lol.